How do I pass a head-tail linked list to a function immutably?
If I need to pass a reference to an int immutably, I can pass it as a const int* to a function, as opposed to int*. This also helps the interface show that the pointed data won't be mutated.
Now I have a deque with a doubly linked list under the hood, how can I pass it immutably ? passing it as const will do nothing as it will only ensure immutability of the pointers not the pointed data
Minimal example:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    int val;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
};

typedef struct {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
} Deque;


int deque_size(Deque dq) {
    int sz = 0;
    Node* current = dq.head;
    while (current)
    {
        current = current->next;
        sz++;
    }

    // surprise
    if (dq.head)
        dq.head->val = 42;
    return sz;
}

int main(void) {
    Deque dq;
    dq.head = NULL;
    dq.tail = NULL;

    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->val = 1;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;

    dq.head = node;
    dq.tail = node;

    printf("first value: %d\n", dq.head->val);
    printf("deque size: %d\n", deque_size(dq));
    printf("first value: %d\n", dq.head->val);
}

Observed output:
first value: 1
deque size: 1
first value: 42

deque_size has sneakily mutated the data structure.
Expected behaviour:
the compiler wouldn't allow me to mutate the data, or at least I would like the API of the module to ensure to the user that I pinky promise won't mutate it.
EDIT
Basically I would want some way to emulate the behaviour of this C++ snippet
#include <deque>

int deque_size(const std::deque<int>& dq)
{
    // does not compile
    dq.pop_front();
    return dq.size();
}

with a fully mutable Deque that I can reference/send immutably to functions like deque.size() or deque.is_empty(), but can also send mutably to other functions like deque.pop_front() or deque.clear()

Pass a const Deque *dq, there is no other way in C without a pointer.

@pts a function deque_size( const Deque *dq ) could still modify dq->head->val what should be prohibited if I understand the question correctly

OT: Deque should have a size field, so the size doesn't need to be recalculated each time which can be expensive.

@pts const Duque* only disallows reseating the pointer, not mutating the pointed data
@Jabberwocky this is beside the point, the problem still happens for any function that's not supposed to mutate the data, like peek or is_empty

C's type system will not give you the sort of promises that more modern languages have. In C you have to use conventions and comments to understand mutation, ownership, and so on.

@PaulHankin this is the conclusion I got too with the people I've been talking, C is the Wild West, everything is just bytes and const is merely a suggestion, but I can hopefully rely on semantics to convey the presence/absence of side effects. Then it's the second part of my question in the Expected behaviour section. What conventions/patterns can I use to pinky promise the user that I won't mutate their data ?

C isn't the wild west, it just doesn't give you ways to express invariants like modern languages. Everything is not just bytes and const is not merely a suggestion -- it just doesn't promise everything you want it to promise. To convey that your function does not mutate the deque, you can add a comment, for example // does not mutate the deque..

But if you want to write a function that actually cannot modify the queue on account of the form of its parameter declarations, then I think you'll have trouble finding that even in more modern languages.  Don't raise abstract types and inheritance in that regard, for the clever enough and determined enough function can generally pierce polymorphism to work with an object according to its actual type, its declared type notwithstanding.

If you were doing this in an OOP language, you'd probably use an ImmutableDeque class where all the members are declared const or const Node*const. This is how you get recursive const-ness.

But there is no const in your code, so no surprise also.

You can have a struct with all members const and also declare the pointers const. This way the compiler  will not let you inadvertently change anything. But a const Thing* const can be cast to anything so once you pass a pointer around there is no warranty of immutability.
